# CS50 week4 filter less, How can I get a copy of a array?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to get a copy of the RGBTRIPLE image array

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE arrayCopy = image[height][width];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            printf("%i", arrayCopy[i][w].rgbtRed);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

The problem is when I want to print out a value it doesn't work
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A copy of the whole 2D array?

```
RGBTRIPLE arrayCopy[height][width];
memcpy(arrayCopy, image, sizeof arrayCopy);
//not sizeof image, it is a pointer to an array, not an array
```

or just a pointer to `image`?

```
RGBTRIPLE (*arrayCopy)[width] = image;
```

usage is the same as you already did.

Comment: is RGBTRIPLE arrayCopy[height][width] making a new rgbtripple array? but with a new name?

Comment: no, `RGBTRIPLE arrayCopy[height][width];` just creates a 2D array with the same size as `image`, the `memcpy` copies the array.